# How do I fix <DEL> behavior on macOS in VIM 8.1?

Tags: key-bindings, macos, original-vim

I've recently installed "huge" VIM 8.1 with Lua support (on macOS via MacPorts). This installation is side-by-side with my "normal" VIM 8.0 which lacks Lua support, so I have access to both versions. The `<DELETE>` key behaves differently in "huge" VIM 8.1 than it does in "normal" VIM 8.0.

Say I have the phrase `GIVE REASON HERE` and I want to cut/move the word `REASON`  I would `fR` then `v` then `fH` then `<DELETE>` (to backspace over the "H" and remove it from the selection) then `x` to cut the word `REASON` *(Yes; there are different ways to do this. This is a contrived example to illustrate the issue I need to resolve.)*

In "normal" VIM 8.0, this works fine. In "huge" VIM 8.1, when I hit the `<DELETE>` key to backspace over the "H", it instead deletes the word `REASON`. I read *many* online posts about how to fix this, quite a few of them were contradictory. These ranged from using `stty`, mapping/unmapping keybinds, using `set backspace`, and so on. I tried them all - in both their "do this" and "don't do this" configurations - and not a single one helped.

I want `<DELETE>` in VIM 8.1 to behave the same as it does in VIM 8.0; how do I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the [faq](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4)

Comment: I'm trying to understand why VIM 8.0 and VIM 8.1 are sufficiently different that keystrokes behave differently when there is no other difference in the environment. I can find no mention of mapping differences between 8.0 and 8.1 in the documentation. Nor can I find a anything to indicate a difference when reviewing the list of changes between 8.0 and 8.1. I've read the FAQ; I'm not trying to create or modify a mapping. If I _need_ to change a mapping, there's been no explanation as to why.

Comment: Well, why the faq talks about how to map a key, the principle is still the same. First find out what keys is actually **seen** by vim. Then we can have a look at how to fix this. Also note, you did not mention, whether you did run this in a terminal or in a gui and what exact version you used. Also $TERM might make a difference, if using terminal vim. So still missing quite a bit of information.

Comment: macOS (various; 10.11 through 10.14); iTerm2 3.2.8; bash 3.2, bash 4.2; VIM 8.0.1283, VIM 8.1.577; $TERM=screen-256color, $TERM=xterm-256color, $TERM=xterm; My keyboard emits 0x08 for `^H`, 0x7F for `<DELETE>`, and 0x08 for `fn-<DELETE>`; `vmap <BS>` reports `No mapping found`; `vmap <Del>` reports `No mapping found`

Comment: Not to be rude, but I don't see how/why any of that matters. Literally, the _only_ thing that changed was moving from VIM 8.0 to 8.1. Version 8.1 is doing something differently; it's not my environment. This point is driven home by the fact that I can run both versions of VIM side-by-side and experience the different behavior live.

Comment: The very first paragraph of the mentioned faq talks about what key vim sees. So what does it see? if you enter insert mode press `<c-v>` and press the `DEL` key, what does it print in both versions? Also what is the output of `:set k_kD?` in both versions?

Comment: Both versions show `^?` when I enter `<c-v>` then press `DEL` When I do `:set k_kD?` I get `E518: Unknown option: k_kD?` but when I do `:set t_kD?` I get `t_kD <Del> ^[[3~` on both.

Comment: Hm, as far as I can tell, this behavior is the default behaviour of `del` in visual mode (and I can't remember that this has been changed within the release of Vim 8 or 8.1. If you don't like that, try to map it away. Since you want it to behave like `Backspace`, doesn't `xmap <del> <bs>` do what you want?